Remotely detect if a PAC file is set up on a device on the network
Hey apologies if this is a dumb question but I have been searching for a a few hours and I'm getting no where.
Internal network; I want to check ideally with a script whether a PAC file has been set up on all devices.
Id like to use PowerShell if possible? I honestly imagined this would be a one liner but nothing seems to be working or seems to look at the proxy details and not if there is a PAC file.
What I have tried:
Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' -Name ProxyEnable, ProxyServer
But this gives an output of "ProxyEnable  : 0" even when there is a pac file and it is working correctly?!
Sorry this is not my typical field of expertise so I'm a bit lost. Anyone able to give me a resource to read up or a pointer.

My understanding is that "ProxyEnable" refers to Manual Proxy settings, which you have disabled because you have enabled "Use a Setup Script" and configured a PAC url instead that will tell the system when to use or not use the proxy. AutoDetect is also set to 0 if you use a PAC script. I can confirm on my systems that use a PAC file configuration, ProxyEnable is 0. if ProxyEnable = 1, then the proxy will always be used, and the only exception to that would be if you had enabled bypassing the proxy for internal addresses.

also note that if you disable "Use Setup Script" in the settings UI, the "AutoConfigURL" registry value is deleted, so you can check if PAC is enabled, simply by checking if that reg value exists.

The automatic configuration script file is defined in that same registry location, but with a different name, AutoConfigURL. Try this instead:
Get-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings' -Name AutoConfigURL |
  Select AutoConfigURL   

AutoConfigURL   
-------------   
example:\path\to\file.pac

It will just error if the setting is blank

As discussed in the comments, if the reg value "AutoConfigURL" exists in the registry, then proxying using that PAC file is enabled. The other option "EnableProxy" should be "0" (off) if Proxy Auto configuration is enabled. When you disable Proxy Auto Configuration script settings, the reg value "AutoConfigURL" is deleted.
To determine if the system is configured to use a PAC, Try something like this in PS:
$regKeyPath = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
$regValueName = "AutoConfigURL"
$valueExists = (Get-Item $regKeyPath -EA Ignore).Property -contains $regValueName
If ($valueExists) {
    Return $true
}
Return $false

The script will check the configured path for the configured value name, ignoring errors if the path does not exist.
This answer is based on resources found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648931/test-if-registry-value-exists
